# angular, how to transform XML response to JSON via interceptor

Tags: angular, interceptor

I have been struggling with how to transform XML response I get from the server to JSON format, using an interceptor. For the transform, I am using xml2json and the plugin works fine, so no problem there.

However, my goal is to change the response body via an interceptor. The code so far is the following:

Service:

```
  getData(query) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.SERVER_URL + query, {responseType: 'text'} ).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          resolve( JSON.parse(data) );
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Interceptor:

```
  intercept( req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req)
      .retry(3)
      .map( (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

          // xml2js transform
          parseString(event.body, function(e, res) {
            if (e != null) {
              return (e);
            }

            event = (event as HttpResponse<any>).clone({
              body: JSON.stringify(res)
            });
            return event;
          });
        }

        return event;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return Observable.of(err);
      });
  }
```

The code is working but what I am doing is a slow workaround: The interceptor is performing the conversion by `parseString()` and then `JSON.stringify(res)` stringifies the result. This string then eventually reaches the success handler of http.get and I return with `JSON.parse(data)`.

If I don't stringify the response body, then the error handler of the http is called, because I guess it is expecting text (string) and not json. But if I set the http responseType to json, then the interceptor is receiving an empty object as `event`.. So how could I eliminate the stringify/parse calls?

Every help is appreciated, thanks :)